# LOAD METADATA ERROR on Buffered SmoothStreaming on Chromecast

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, smooth-streaming

Folks,

We've faced a problem with a playback of the buffered streams and it will be great if someone can help with it.

Log:

```
############ mediaManagerMessage:LOAD {"type":"load","H":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"lb":true,"data":{"autoplay":true,"currentTime":0,"requestId":3,"media":{"contentId":"http://.../shss/.../3.ism/Manifest","streamType":"BUFFERED","contentType":"application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml","metadata":{"title":"KYLE XY S03","metadataType":0,"subtitle":"Afl. 01: To C.I.R., With Love"},"duration":0}},"senderId":"24:..."} (index):122
############ mediaProtocol:SmoothStreaming (index):122
############ mediaElementState:Load Start (index):122
XHR finished loading: GET "https://.../shss/.../3.ism/Manifest?start=0&end=-1&device=Orion-HSS". media_player.js:1195
2Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'buffered' property from 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source. media_player.js:2265
############ mediaElementState:Error (index):122
############ n.Event {originalEvent: Event, type: "error", isDefaultPrevented: function, timeStamp: 1413827863971, jQuery211209524504924193025: true…} (index):124
 [413.425s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error cast_receiver.js:18
############ mediaManagerMessage:LOAD METADATA ERROR: {"senderId":"...","message":{"autoplay":true,"currentTime":0,"requestId":3,"media":{"contentId":"http://.../3.ism/Manifest","streamType":"BUFFERED","contentType":"application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml","metadata":{"title":"KYLE XY S03","metadataType":0,"subtitle":"Afl. 01: To C.I.R., With Love"},"duration":0}}} (index):122
 [413.452s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending error message to 24:... cast_receiver.js:18
 [413.460s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"24:...","data":"{\"requestId\":3,\"type\":\"LOAD_FAILED\"}"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [412.904s] [cast.player.api.Player] error media_player.js:715
############ mediaHostState:Fatal Error: code = 1
```

I can see that Manifest has been requested with 200 OK, but 2 subsequent audio & video calls are cancelled. Our streams are encoded with h.264.

Comment: There isn't enough data to comment. Please open a ticket on our issue tracker and provide a full console log (not just a piece, but rather the full log) in addition to a stream sample that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Created https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=457